# Python Matplotlib MouseEvent xy vs. xydata

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, onclick, mouseevent

I am working on a project to make a mouse click interactive pixel map (created with pyplot) using Python 3.4 and Matplotlib 1.4.3. I am using the matplotlib.backend_bases.MouseEvent class to make my figure interactive. I'm just getting started, and so far I have:

```
# Define an on_click() function that will print event data upon mouseclick
 def on_click(event):
        """Print event data on mouseclick"""
        print(event)
```

When I click on the figure, here's the kind of output I get:

MPL MouseEvent: xy=(289,265) xydata=(24.5956632653,21.9489795918) button=1 dblclick=False inaxes=Axes(0.141923,0.1;0.603077x0.8)

Can anyone tell me what the xy part means? It's a 50x50 pixel map, so the xydata is the pixel position of the mouse click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the position from left and bottom of `canvas`, respectively.

Here is the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html):

> the following attributes
>
> `x`- x position - pixels from left of canvas
>      `y`- y position - pixels from bottom of canvas
>
> `canvas`- the `FigureCanvas` instance generating the event